# How to concat two response, invoke in sequence. Second http call depends on the value returned by the first?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Now I have that code and try to return concerted value from two http Call

```
defer(() => {
                return this.service.save1(data)
                    .pipe(
                        concatMap((result) => {
                            if (result) {
                                return of({
                                    ...result,
                                    c: this.service.save2(result.id , this.obj).subscribe()    
                                })
                            }
                            return of({});
                        }),
                        catchError(err => throwError(err)),
            }).subscribe((result) => {
                if (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                }
            },
```

In cosnole.log(result) now we have the whole object result + c: as Observable
I'd like to return all fields returned by the first call and c: as an array of objects

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to subscribe inside the operators. Instead you could return the observable directly and subscribe where the result is required.

1. Use `filter` pipe to ignore undefined responses from the first request. This way the `if` conditions inside the `concatMap` and subscription isn't needed.
2. Pipe a `map` to the second observable to combine both the results.

Try the following

```js
return this.service.save1(data).pipe(
  filter((result) => (!!result))   // <-- go ahead only if `result` is defined
  concatMap((result) =>
    this.service.save2(result.id, this.obj).pipe(
      map((c) => ({
        ...result,
        c: c
      }))
    )
  ),
  catchError(err => throwError(err))   // <-- `catchError` is redundant at the moment
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can format the response by piping the response of observable `c`. there is no need to subscribe to that observable, it will automatically subscribe to the value with concatMap

```
 defer(() => {
    return this.service.save1(data)
        .pipe(
            concatMap((result) => {
                if (result) {
                    return this.service.save2(result.id , this.obj).pipe(
                            map((data) => [...data, result]) // all the data is 
                                                             // available here, format 
                                                             // as you would like
                }
                return of({});
            }),
            catchError(err => throwError(err)),
}).subscribe((result) => {
    if (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
},
```